# R strsplit using Regex

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I want to use R to split some chat messages, here is an example:

```
example <- "[29.01.18, 23:33] Alice: Ist das hier ein Chatverlauf?\n[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Ja ist es!\n[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Der ist dazu da die funktionsweise des Parsers zu demonstrieren\n[29.01.18, 23:46] Alice: ‎PTT-20180129-WA0025.opus (Datei angehängt)\n[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Ah, er kann also auch erkennen ob Voicemails gesendet wurden!\n[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Das ist praktisch!\n[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Oder?\n[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: ja |Emoji_Grinning_Face_With_Smiling_Eyes| \n[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: und Emojis gehen auch!\n[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Was ist mit normalen Smilies?\n[29.01.18, 23:49] Alice: ‎Keine Ahnung, lass uns das doch mal ausprobieren\n[29.01.18, 23:50] Bob: Alles klar :) :D\n[29.01.18, 23:51] Alice: Scheint zu funktionieren!:P\n[29.01.18, 23:51] Bob: Meinst du, dass URLS auch erkannt werden?\n[29.01.18, 23:52] Bob: ‎Schick doch mal eine zum ausprobieren!\n[29.01.18, 23:53] Alice: https://github.com/JuKo007\n[29.01.18, 23:58] Alice: ‎Scheint zu funktionieren!\n[29.01.18, 23:59] Alice: Sehr schön!\n[30.01.18, 00:00] Alice: Damit sollten sich WhatsApp Verläufe besser quantifizieren lassen!\n[30.01.18, 00:02] Bob: ‎Alles klar, los gehts  |Emoji_Relieved_Face| \n"
```

Basically, I want to split the string right in front of the date-time indicator in the brackets, here is what I tried so far:

```
  # Cutting the textblock into individual messages
  chat <- strsplit(example,"(?=\\[\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d, \\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])",perl=TRUE)
  chat <- unlist(chat)
```

The weird thing is, that in the output, it seems that the split occurs *after* the first square bracket, not in front:

```
 [1] "["                                                                                           
 [2] "29.01.18, 23:33] Alice: Ist das hier ein Chatverlauf?\n"                                     
 [3] "["                                                                                           
 [4] "29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Ja ist es!\n"                                                          
 [5] "["                                                                                           
 [6] "29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Der ist dazu da die funktionsweise des Parsers zu demonstrieren\n"     
 [7] "["                                                                                           
 [8] "29.01.18, 23:46] Alice: ‎PTT-20180129-WA0025.opus (Datei angehängt)\n"                        
 [9] "["                                                                                           
[10] "29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Ah, er kann also auch erkennen ob Voicemails gesendet wurden!\n"       
[11] "["                                                                                           
[12] "29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Das ist praktisch!\n"                                                  
[13] "["                                                                                           
[14] "29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Oder?\n"                                                               
[15] "["                                                                                           
[16] "29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: ja |Emoji_Grinning_Face_With_Smiling_Eyes| \n"                       
[17] "["                                                                                           
[18] "29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: und Emojis gehen auch!\n"                                            
[19] "["                                                                                           
[20] "29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Was ist mit normalen Smilies?\n"                                       
[21] "["                                                                                           
[22] "29.01.18, 23:49] Alice: ‎Keine Ahnung, lass uns das doch mal ausprobieren\n"                  
[23] "["                                                                                           
[24] "29.01.18, 23:50] Bob: Alles klar :) :D\n"                                                    
[25] "["                                                                                           
[26] "29.01.18, 23:51] Alice: Scheint zu funktionieren!:P\n"                                       
[27] "["                                                                                           
[28] "29.01.18, 23:51] Bob: Meinst du, dass URLS auch erkannt werden?\n"                           
[29] "["                                                                                           
[30] "29.01.18, 23:52] Bob: ‎Schick doch mal eine zum ausprobieren!\n"                              
[31] "["                                                                                           
[32] "29.01.18, 23:53] Alice: https://github.com/JuKo007\n"                                        
[33] "["                                                                                           
[34] "29.01.18, 23:58] Alice: ‎Scheint zu funktionieren!\n"                                         
[35] "["                                                                                           
[36] "29.01.18, 23:59] Alice: Sehr schön!\n"                                                       
[37] "["                                                                                           
[38] "30.01.18, 00:00] Alice: Damit sollten sich WhatsApp Verläufe besser quantifizieren lassen!\n"
[39] "["                                                                                           
[40] "30.01.18, 00:02] Bob: ‎Alles klar, los gehts  |Emoji_Relieved_Face| \n"
```

When I try to test the Regex pattern [online](https://regex101.com/r/T2wB2o/1) or use it in python, it works just as intended, so to me it seems that this is a feature of the strsplit function? Any recommendation on how to change my R code to make this work are very welcome! I know that it would be easy to just paste this output back together to get my desired output but I would really like to understand whats going on with strsplit and do it properly instead of patching it back together. What I want is:

```
 [1] "[29.01.18, 23:33] Alice: Ist das hier ein Chatverlauf?\n"                                                                                                                           
 [2] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Ja ist es!\n"                                                                                                                                                  
 [3] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Der ist dazu da die funktionsweise des Parsers zu demonstrieren\n"                                                                                         
 [4] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Alice: ‎PTT-20180129-WA0025.opus (Datei angehängt)\n"                                                                                                      
[5] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Ah, er kann also auch erkennen ob Voicemails gesendet wurden!\n"                                                                                          
[6] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Das ist praktisch!\n"                                                                                                                                    
[7] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Oder?\n"                                                                                                                                                   
[8] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: ja |Emoji_Grinning_Face_With_Smiling_Eyes| \n"                                                                                                            
[9] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: und Emojis gehen auch!\n"                                                                                                                          
[10] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Was ist mit normalen Smilies?\n"                                                                                                                         
[11] "[29.01.18, 23:49] Alice: ‎Keine Ahnung, lass uns das doch mal ausprobieren\n"                                                                                                    
[12] "[29.01.18, 23:50] Bob: Alles klar :) :D\n"                                                                                                                                       
[13] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Alice: Scheint zu funktionieren!:P\n"                                                                                                                        
[14] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Bob: Meinst du, dass URLS auch erkannt werden?"                                                                                                             
[15] "[29.01.18, 23:52] Bob: ‎Schick doch mal eine zum ausprobieren!\n"                                                                                                                       
[16] "[29.01.18, 23:53] Alice: https://github.com/JuKo007\n"                                                                                                                                  
[17] "[29.01.18, 23:58] Alice: ‎Scheint zu funktionieren!\n"                                                                                                                                  
[18] "[29.01.18, 23:59] Alice: Sehr schön!\n"                                                                                                                                                
[19] "[30.01.18, 00:00] Alice: Damit sollten sich WhatsApp Verläufe besser quantifizieren lassen!\n"                                                                                           
[20] "[30.01.18, 00:02] Bob: ‎Alles klar, los gehts  |Emoji_Relieved_Face| \n"
```

Comment: I think you have received the correct answer already. Just in case you want a more automated way to deal with WhatsApp data, you can check out this package: https://github.com/JBGruber/rwhatsapp

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me to your package! That is indeed handy! In fact, I was in the middle of writing a parser myself for a research project I'm currently working on. My (still relatively empty repo) is here: https://github.com/JuKo007/WhatsAppParser/

Comment: I think my parser is pretty much ready and robust. The only reason I didn't publish on CRAN so far is that I think it's a rather small contribution for an R package. If you want to put some work into it, you could add to my repo (issues and PRs). I'm happy to add you as contributor for a substantial PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead `(?!^)` to assert not the start of the string.

Your updated line might look like:

```
chat <- strsplit(example,"(?!^)(?=\\[\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d, \\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])",perl=TRUE)
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/KlRaFp)

Result

```
 [1] "[29.01.18, 23:33] Alice: Ist das hier ein Chatverlauf?\n"                                     
 [2] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Ja ist es!\n"                                                          
 [3] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Der ist dazu da die funktionsweise des Parsers zu demonstrieren\n"     
 [4] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Alice: ‎PTT-20180129-WA0025.opus (Datei angehängt)\n"                        
 [5] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Ah, er kann also auch erkennen ob Voicemails gesendet wurden!\n"       
 [6] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Das ist praktisch!\n"                                                  
 [7] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Oder?\n"                                                               
 [8] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: ja |Emoji_Grinning_Face_With_Smiling_Eyes| \n"                       
 [9] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: und Emojis gehen auch!\n"                                            
[10] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Was ist mit normalen Smilies?\n"                                       
[11] "[29.01.18, 23:49] Alice: ‎Keine Ahnung, lass uns das doch mal ausprobieren\n"                  
[12] "[29.01.18, 23:50] Bob: Alles klar :) :D\n"                                                    
[13] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Alice: Scheint zu funktionieren!:P\n"                                       
[14] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Bob: Meinst du, dass URLS auch erkannt werden?\n"                           
[15] "[29.01.18, 23:52] Bob: ‎Schick doch mal eine zum ausprobieren!\n"                              
[16] "[29.01.18, 23:53] Alice: https://github.com/JuKo007\n"                                        
[17] "[29.01.18, 23:58] Alice: ‎Scheint zu funktionieren!\n"                                         
[18] "[29.01.18, 23:59] Alice: Sehr schön!\n"                                                       
[19] "[30.01.18, 00:00] Alice: Damit sollten sich WhatsApp Verläufe besser quantifizieren lassen!\n"
[20] "[30.01.18, 00:02] Bob: ‎Alles klar, los gehts  |Emoji_Relieved_Face| \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringi` and extract the info you want by slightly modifying the end of your pattern (i.e., matching everything until the next `[`). You could include more of your pattern to ensure there aren't any false-matches but this should get your started. Good luck!

```
library(stringi)

stri_extract_all(example, regex = "\\[\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d, \\d\\d:\\d\\d\\][^\\[]*")
[[1]]
 [1] "[29.01.18, 23:33] Alice: Ist das hier ein Chatverlauf?\n"                                     
 [2] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Ja ist es!\n"                                                          
 [3] "[29.01.18, 23:45] Bob: Der ist dazu da die funktionsweise des Parsers zu demonstrieren\n"     
 [4] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Alice: \016PTT-20180129-WA0025.opus (Datei angehängt)\n"                    
 [5] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Ah, er kann also auch erkennen ob Voicemails gesendet wurden!\n"       
 [6] "[29.01.18, 23:46] Bob: Das ist praktisch!\n"                                                  
 [7] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Oder?\n"                                                               
 [8] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: ja |Emoji_Grinning_Face_With_Smiling_Eyes| \n"                       
 [9] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Alice: und Emojis gehen auch!\n"                                            
[10] "[29.01.18, 23:47] Bob: Was ist mit normalen Smilies?\n"                                       
[11] "[29.01.18, 23:49] Alice: \016Keine Ahnung, lass uns das doch mal ausprobieren\n"              
[12] "[29.01.18, 23:50] Bob: Alles klar :) :D\n"                                                    
[13] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Alice: Scheint zu funktionieren!:P\n"                                       
[14] "[29.01.18, 23:51] Bob: Meinst du, dass URLS auch erkannt werden?\n"                           
[15] "[29.01.18, 23:52] Bob: \016Schick doch mal eine zum ausprobieren!\n"                          
[16] "[29.01.18, 23:53] Alice: https://github.com/JuKo007\n"                                        
[17] "[29.01.18, 23:58] Alice: \016Scheint zu funktionieren!\n"                                     
[18] "[29.01.18, 23:59] Alice: Sehr schön!\n"                                                       
[19] "[30.01.18, 00:00] Alice: Damit sollten sich WhatsApp Verläufe besser quantifizieren lassen!\n"
[20] "[30.01.18, 00:02] Bob: \016Alles klar, los gehts  |Emoji_Relieved_Face| \n"
```

Comment: Yes, this works on my particular example that I posted here but in the files there are many instances where there are newlines within the messages as well, so that wouldn't work. I shouldǘe included this in the example, my bad!

Comment: No worries--if you update, i'll edit or delete this if I can't crack it.

Comment: @JuKo, just updated it. Hopefully this works better!